# pinterest sharing not working with AngularJS and laravel framework

Tags: php, angularjs, pinterest

When I am using any code related with php + AngularJS then its not able to share anything on pinterest direct from our application.

Like:

```
$pinterest = new PinterestAPI('487992287213444318092', '3e49484c42b9a43716b6306c43083aaed2860a879d5f6ef112c01e1');
$loginurl = $pinterest->auth->getLoginUrl('http://localhost:3000', array('read_public, write_public, read_relationships,write_relationships'), 'code');
```

Any code structure like:

https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/php/app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php

this code structure working fine with others sharing.

Comment: I have implemented pinterest sharing now its working with my code thanks for giving me response.
https://in.pinterest.com/pin/785807834952140424/
now pinterest is working fine with unificationengine but now I am facing one problem with unification engine sharing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228739/xing-sharing-not-working-on-localhost how can I test my application in local ?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you are only able to share public available URLs. You are **not able to share local URLs**. You need to know that the pinteres API is crawling your ShareUrl. This is not possible on your local environment because the web crawler could not access it.

The `PDF.pin` syntax is the following. It **does work with public web URLs**.

```
PDK.pin( ImageUrl, Description, ShareUrl, function(){
  // Do whatever you like
});
```