# Xing sharing not working on localhost

Tags: angularjs, laravel, xing

I am using angularjs and laravel when I am sending a message from link or by code then I am getting invalid URL error

```
<a  href="https://www.xing-share.com/app/user?op=share;sc_p=xing-share;url=http://localhost:3000">Share on Xing</a>-->
<a class="xing customer share" href="https://www.xing.com/social_plugins/share?url=http://localhost:3000" title="Xing Share" target="_blank">Xing</a>
```

Comment: Please mark the right answer m8.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [xing share documentation](https://dev.xing.com/plugins/share_button/docs) you **can not share local links**. Xing will crawl you shared link but this will not work while the xing crawler is unable to access your local environment.

A share link must be a public URL which is able to access by the xing crawler.

#### Image by xing share button documentation:

[image]

Comment: How Can I test my sharing information ?. I have implemented so many sharing but its giving me localhost error

Comment: @Parveenkumar create a Webhost with an public URL which is available in WAN.